# Subset a corpus by meta data?

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I feel like this should be easier, but I cannot figure this out. 
How do I filter out documents from a corpus based on metadata.  To be more specific, I have a corpus of 576 documents, each of which has the tag 'Section'.  Section has a number of different values such as, "News", "Editorial" and "Comment".
How do i use tm_filter to filter out documents, say, that have "Editorial" and or "Comment" in this?
I'm sorry I haven't provided reproducible data. I don't really know how to go about producing a sample corpus.

Comment: Consider using **quanteda** instead to create a corpus, where the Section variable is a document variable in the corpus. Then you can subset using `subset(myCorpus, Section == "Editorial")`. See `?corpus` on how to create the corpus from your documents. It's quite straightforward.

Comment: OK, thanks for that. I wasn't aware of the quanteda package.  Before  I step on the learning curve to learn that one, once I've filtered out my documents, can I take the corpus back to tm (crudely speaking) for analysis?

Comment: You can always get the texts from a quanteda corpus using `texts(myCorpus)`, and then you could put these into VectorSource(). But no need: quanteda can do all of the analysis too. Worth checking out.