# R- Subset a corpus by meta data (id) matching partial strings

Tags: regex, r, tm

I'm using the R (3.2.3) tm-package (0.6-2) and would like to subset my corpus according to partial string  matches contained with the metadatum "id". 
For example, I would like to filter all documents that contain the string "US" within the "id" column. The string "US" would be preceded and followed by various characters and numbers.

I have found a similar example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33698428/subset-a-corpus-by-meta-data). It is recommended to download the `quanteda` package but I think this should also be possible with the `tm` package.

Another more relevant answer to a similar problem is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399093/how-to-filter-meta-data-by-user-defined-statements-in-r/34416317#34416317). I have tried to adapt that sample code to my context. However, I don't manage to incorporate the partial string matching.

I imagine there might be multiple things wrong with my code so far. 
What I have so far looks like this:

```
US <- tm_filter(corpus, FUN = function(corpus, filter) any(meta(corpus)["id"] == filter), grep(".*US.*", corpus))
```

And I receive the following error message:

```
Error in structure(as.character(x), names = names(x)) : 
'names' attribute [3811] must be the same length as the vector [3]
```

I'm also not sure how to come up with a reproducible example simulating my problem for this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could work like this:

```
library(tm)
reut21578 <- system.file("texts", "crude", package = "tm")
(corp <- VCorpus(DirSource(reut21578), list(reader = readReut21578XMLasPlain)))
# <<VCorpus>>
# Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
# Content:  documents: 20
(idx <- grep("0", sapply(meta(corp, "id"), paste0), value=TRUE))
#   502   704   708 
# "502" "704" "708" 
(corpsubset <- corp[idx] )
# <<VCorpus>>
# Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
# Content:  documents: 3
```

You are looking for `"US"` instead of `"0"`. Have a look at `?grep` for details (e.g. `fixed=TRUE`).

Comment: Thank you very much! It does exaclty what I need.